# prevent jquery to append duplicate values in a table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting duplicate values while calling JSON response from AJAX using jQuery and PHP. The code is running perfectly but it is giving duplicate entries while selecting drop down list. There are two drop down list first one calls from db and based on first one the values get propagated in the second one. And while selecting selecting second one it will call a java script which Return JSON response from AJAX using jQuery but in a duplicated value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#employee").change(function() {    
  //var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
  //var dataString = 'empid='+ id; 
  var b_code = $(this).find(":selected").val();
  var dataString = 'empid='+ b_code;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getData.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'JSON',
  data: dataString,
        success: function(response){
            var len = response.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var id = response[i].id;
                var X1 = response[i].X1;
                var X2 = response[i].X2;
                var X3 = response[i].X3;
            var X4 = response[i].X4;
            var X5 = response[i].X5;
    
                var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + (i+1) + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + X1 + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + X2 + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + X3+ "</td>" +
               "<td align='center'>" + X4 + "</td>" +
               "<td align='center'>" + X5+ "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
     
                $("#userTable").append(tr_str);
            }
   } 
  })
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TSP</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="csss/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="csss/style1.css">
  <!--</style> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){             
               $("#district").change(function(){
                     var district=$("#district").val();
                     $.ajax({
                      type:"post",
                      url:"getblock.php",
                      data:"district="+district,
                      success:function(data){
                              $("#employee").html(data);
                      }
                     });
               });
           });
      </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;"> 
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3"> 
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title"><center>Select District & Block</center></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
  District :
        <select name="district" id="district">
          <option>-select your district-</option>
       <?php 
       include "db_connect.php"; 
        //$result=mysqli_query("SELECT DTCode,DTName from district order by DTName");
  $sql = "SELECT DTCode,DTName from district order by DTName";
  $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
        while($district = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
        echo "<option value=$district[DTCode]>$district[DTName]</option>";
       } ?>
       </select>
 
       Block :
       <select name="block" id="employee">
        <option>-select your block-</option>
  </select>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
  
 
<div class="container">
   <table id="userTable" border="2" >
      <tr>
       <th width="5%">S.no</th>
       <th width="10%">X1</th>
       <th width="10%">X2</th>
       <th width="10%">X3</th>
    <th width="10%">X4</th>
    <th width="6%">X5</th>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>

</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/getDatan.js"></script>
```

Comment: you could add each of the entry id's or the entry themselves in a list, and then on each iteration check if the current one is within that dictionary/list, if so just skip over it.

Comment: Can you please share any reference how to do it.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you could use an array which stores the ids that you have passed, and on each iteration you can check whether you have a duplicate one.

Here is an example:

```
var testArray = [];

var len = response.length;
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        if($.inArray(response[i].id, testArray)){ // check whether you have went over it already
            continue;
        }
        testArray.push(response[i].id); // add the current id to the list and thats how you will avoid duplicates, assuming that the IDs are duplicate
        var id = response[i].id;
        var X1 = response[i].X1;
        var X2 = response[i].X2;
        var X3 = response[i].X3;
        var X4 = response[i].X4;
        var X5 = response[i].X5;

        var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                "<td align='center'>" + (i+1) + "</td>" +
                "<td align='center'>" + X1 + "</td>" +
                "<td align='center'>" + X2 + "</td>" +
                "<td align='center'>" + X3+ "</td>" +
                        "<td align='center'>" + X4 + "</td>" +
                          "<td align='center'>" + X5+ "</td>" +
                "</tr>";

        $("#userTable").append(tr_str);
```

Hope this helps!